# Installing Magento 2 develop branch

Tags: magento2, installation

Having hit a possible bug in Magento 2.0.2 I wanted to download the develop branch and see if it had been fixed. I pulled this down and ran composer install. It removed all the magento community packages and now Magento 2 says it is missing classes. As well it might.

Looking in the composer.json currently in the develop branch, unlike the released versions it has no entry for magento/product-community-edition - instead it has a bunch of supporting libraries and all the magento packages in a "replace" section. I'm supposing this is so that forked version of the packages can be worked on. But I have no idea how to get to that point.

I cannot find any documentation anywhere for how to get hold of the missing libraries - do I add the magento/product-community-edition line back in with dev-master as the version? Or do I manually download the packages and put them somewhere? Where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the github repository, the packages are already contained. That's why it says replace.

All the Magento Modules can be found under app/code/Magento
The Themes are under app/design/
The Magento Framework is under lib/internal

If you are missing classes, most likely they are autogenerated classes like factories, proxies or interceptors.

To have them autogenerated on the fly you could activate the developer mode or to generate them via console command you can run bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thank-you - that worked after running bin/magento setup:upgrade, clearing DI and then compiling the DI classes.

So this seems to have been little to do with being on a dev branch and more to do with needing to know that DI compilation is needed if you change the location of classes while you have a working installation, as I assume that a new installation would be handled by the install script.

All this could have been avoided if I'd got round to setting developer mode it seems.